# Make UIScrollView with dynamic height subviews work automatically with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, resize

I have the following view structure with its constraints:

```
UIView "parent"
   UIScrollView (leading, trailing, top and bottom to superview)
      - UIView "container" (leading, trailing, top and bottom to UIScrollView, 
                            equal width and height so parent UIView)
         - UIView "A" (leading, trailing, top to UIScrollView, height of 200)
         - UIView "B" (top, leading and trailing to UIView A, height of 140)
         - UIView "C" (top, leading and trailing to UIView B, height >= 88 "rest
                       of the screen until bottom", bottom to UIView "container")
```

"A" and "B" `UIView`'s do not change its size but "C" does. Inside it, I am adding programmatically **n** "labels containers" `UIView` that have different heights depending on the content of **m** `UILabel` that they host.

Right now, I am calculating the size of the **n** `UILabel` with `boundingRectWithSize:` and I am sizing the height of their parent "labels containers" `UIView` that it is being added inside "C" `UIView` setting its height constraint to the sum of all `UILabel`.

Then, I resize "C" `UIView` height constraint so that it is equal to the sum of all added `UIView`.

This is working perfectly on all different screen sizes, portrait and landscape. The `UIScrollView` is showing all three "A", "B" and "C" subviews, having "C" **n** `UIView` that host **m** `UILabel`.

But now I am having troubles when rotating the device. I face the problem that I have to recalculate the size of all `UILabel` to change the height  constraint of all the "labels container" `UIView` and change the "C" `UIView` height constraint so that it can fit everything without large blank spaces between all views.

So my question is: how can I achieve the same behaviour using exclusively `Auto Layout`?

Now I have to recalculate sizes and change height constraints so that everything adapts, but I would love that all `UILabel` resize themselves automatically and fit their content, then the "labels container" `UIView` resize to fit all the `UILabel` and then "C" `UIView` resizes automatically to fit the content.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How many n labels do you have? In this case, I'd use a TableView (that uses that labels as cells), then merge the A and B view with a container, and put in the tableHeaderView. This solves all your issues with calculations.

Comment: @DejanSkledar the number of labels is variable, depends on the server side. All `UIView` added to "C" `UIView` are more complex than I said, they do not only host `UILabel`, but I tried to simplify it at maximum just keeping the "dynamic" part of it... So using `UITableView` in this case would be counterproductive... The idea is to get a behaviour where everything gets resized and all views fit their content automatically...

Comment: Then again what is a TableView? A scrollView with additional features... One of it is exactly what you mentioned: "...everything gets resized and all views fit their content automatically"

Comment: If you set the container view in story board then set height constraint to container view and give outlet to that. Next in coding after adding all labels change container view height constraint "containerConstraint.constant= 150". Now scroll view adjusted automatically.

Comment: Google with **size classes in ios** and check out this post https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Comment: @LeeroyJenkins why aren't you adding constraints to your `UILabel` when you add them dynamically? You have to add constraints to `UILabel`: `Top to prev UILabel, Leading and Trail to UILabel Superview` and do not set the bottom one. After you add last `UILabel` set `Bottom constraints` of your `UILabel Superview` to `Last UILabel`. And that all.

Comment: @Nazir I am already doing that. Without that, I could not get a fully functional `UIScrollView`. The problem is when doing rotations. `UILabel` does not display text the same way in portrait than in landscape, so I have to recalculate the sizes..

Comment: @LeeroyJenkins - with variable number of labels being added, you cannot do this *purely* from Interface Builder, however... you should *not* need to manually calculate sizes. Set up your "C" subview so **its** height is determined by the constraints on its content.

Comment: @DonMag I know, that is why I am adding all those subviews and its constraints using code. I think that I almost got it. I managed to make those subviews to resize correctly but now, when I try to get the size of that `UIView` to change the height constraint to make the `UIScrollView` work, I am getting an incorrect frame...

Comment: Don't try to use the size of the view to change a constraint... Let auto-layout handle it.

Comment: @LeeroyJenkins let me get cleared. Are you calculating height b/c you need to resize content view of UIScrollView? If your UIView "C" is resized then you have to check your UIView container constraints.

Comment: @DonMag That is what I was doing before! I was setting a height constraint to all subviews, so that then I could retrieve it and add it to the `UIScrollView` content height. Now those subviews are resizing correctly thanks to `Auto Layout` but now, when I get the frame of that view to resize the **"C"** `UIView` so that the `UIScrollView` can be scrollable, it returns 0.

Comment: To make it more clear: now I only have to tell `UIScrollView` that has to increase its `constentSize` automatically depending on the part that goes off the screen of the **"C"** `UIView`.

Comment: If you are using auto-layout and constraints, *do not* set .contentSize. If your constraints are set correctly, they will "auto-magically" set the .contentSize of the scroll view. Let me see if I can put something together quickly...

Comment: I know, that is what I am saying :). There is something wrong with my constraints as the `UIScrollView` is not adapting its "`contentSize"` to be able to see all the "container" `UIView`...

Comment: Ok I think I got it... Let me try something... **EDIT: I got it! Now I publish the answer!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was doing three things wrong:

**1st:** I was calculating the height of the labels to set then the size of the "labels container" `UIView` using a height constraint. Height constraints not needed as `Auto Layout` manages everything.

**2nd:** I was modifying the **"C"** `UIView` constraint height manually by adding the height value of each "labels container" `UIView` added.

**3rd:** After fixing the first two steps, I forgot to set the last added `UIView` constraint with its parent view...

Now everything works as expected.

Comment: had posted some solution with where you do not need to calculate anything ) https://github.com/nzmb/External . give me feedback

Comment: @Nazir thank you very much but I am not calculating anything anymore. `Auto Layout` is doing all the work. Now absolutely all `UIView` are resizing automatically, the same with the `UIScrollView` **contentSize**.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge you need to add `TableView` for your **dynamic labels** and to achieve this you have to follow below steps:

**1step :** Add `ScrollView` in your `ViewController`.

**2step :** Add `ContainerView` in ScrollView to manage scroll `constrains`.

**3step :** Add your "**A**" view with fixed size lets say 150px.

**4step :** Add your "**B**" view with fixed size lets say 150px.

**5step :** Add `TableView` for dynamic labels with fixed size 0px. At this step make Outlet of your `tableView` height `Constrains` we will use it in next step.

**6step :** Call your service and add labels in your `tableView`.

in this **6th** step while you are adding labels in your table view means while you reload your tableView do below **code for dynamic heigh constrains**.

**7step :** Now as per your Row height adjust height of table view as mention below.

```
arrListArray = @[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine",@"Ten"];
int rowHeight = 44;
self.tblHeightConstraint.constant = (rowHeight * arrListArray.count);
```

now reload your constrains with below method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                     animations:^{
                         // Called on parent view
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

it will increase your scrollView contain size automatically.

Show sample images :

[image][image][image]

View Constrains Stack :

[image]

Now as per your comment you have to add `CollectionView` in place of `tableView` and add `TableView` in `CollectionViewCell` with your specific design.

Hope this will helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for this awesome answer, but you did not understand exactly my layout. **A** and **B** are correct but **C** contains **n** `UIView` subviews and each one of them contains **m** `UILabel` among other views that do not change dynamically...

Comment: Ok so for that you can use CollectionView in in each n UIView add TableView it will helps to get what you want.

Comment: Hmmm that is something I can consider... I will try it out! Thanks :)